# Writing the values in Google Sheet column via Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a 2 column google sheet, column one (A) has the domain names, and I want to populate whether they are verified in Google Apps or not in the column B respectively.

I wrote the following script-:
When i check for logs, i see that the loop is working fine as i get True/False value to all 4 domain in column A, am facing issues in writing the results to Column B with following script, it seems am missing something around getrange, but not sure.
any help is appreciated.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var data = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
var customer = "my_customer";
function domainList() {
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

  var getDomain = AdminDirectory.Domains.get(customer, data[i])
  var result = JSON.parse(getDomain.verified)
   sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(result)
Logger.log(result)
  } }
```

Comment: I don't think sheet is defined .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define sheet.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
var customer = "my_customer";
function domainList() {
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

  var getDomain = AdminDirectory.Domains.get(customer, data[i])
  var result = JSON.parse(getDomain.verified)
   sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(result)
Logger.log(result)
  } }
```

I think if you will recode your function like this it will work okay.  I disabled a couple of lines just to get the code right.

```
function domainList() 
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data =sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var customer = "my_customer";
  for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
  {
    data[i]=[];
    //var getDomain = AdminDirectory.Domains.get(customer, data[i][0]);
    //var result = JSON.parse(getDomain.verified)
    sheet.getRange(i+1,2).setValue('yes')

  } 
}
```

Comment: thank you, it still puts only first value in B1 and leave B2,B3,B4 blank.

Comment: Your only setting the B1 value  sheet.getRange('B1').setValue(result).  Perhaps you want that to be B + i + 1? or something like that.

Comment: There are several other ways of using getRange read about them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).

Comment: I was able to write to every cell in column B so must  something wrong with  these two lines. //var getDomain = AdminDirectory.Domains.get(customer, data[i][0]);
    //var result = JSON.parse(getDomain.verified)

Comment: thank you, no problem is writing hard core values, but i want to write the result of the result = JSON.parse(getDomain.verified) to column B which isn't working.

Comment: I think that's a G Suite thing.  I can't help you there.